# Write SMILES to SDF in RDKit

Tags: computational-chemistry

I have a file with smiles and I'd like to convert the SMILES to SDF and tag the properties of each molecule, so I can use the SD file in another tool. Here is my code:

```
pp = pd.read_csv('anti.smiles', names=['Smiles', 'BA']) 
pp =  PandasTools.AddMoleculeColumnToFrame(pp,'Smiles','Molecule')
PandasTools.WriteSDF(pp, pp_out, molColName='Molecule', properties=list(pp.columns))
```

And the error I get is this:

```
NameError: name 'pp_out' is not defined
```

Kindly assist

Comment: As-is, this isn't a minimum working example. Where does `PandasTools` come from? Can you add your missing imports so your code is runnable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must give the output file a name: 'pp_out.sdf'

With a smiles-file like

```
c1ccccc1O,Phenol
CCO,Ethanol
```

this works for me

```
import pandas as pd
from rdkit.Chem import PandasTools
pp = pd.read_csv('anti.smiles', names=['Smiles', 'BA']) 
PandasTools.AddMoleculeColumnToFrame(pp,'Smiles','Molecule') # pp = doesn't work for me
PandasTools.WriteSDF(pp, 'pp_out.sdf', molColName='Molecule', properties=list(pp.columns))
```

and gives me this SDF

```
     RDKit          2D

  7  7  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    1.5000    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7500   -1.2990    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.7500   -1.2990    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -1.5000    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
   -0.7500    1.2990    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    0.7500    1.2990    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.5000    2.5981    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  2  0
  2  3  1  0
  3  4  2  0
  4  5  1  0
  5  6  2  0
  6  7  1  0
  6  1  1  0
M  END
>  <Smiles>  (1) 
c1ccccc1O

>  <BA>  (1) 
Phenol

$$$$

     RDKit          2D

  3  2  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0999 V2000
    0.0000    0.0000    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    1.2990    0.7500    0.0000 C   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
    2.5981   -0.0000    0.0000 O   0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
  1  2  1  0
  2  3  1  0
M  END
>  <Smiles>  (2) 
CCO

>  <BA>  (2) 
Ethanol

$$$$
```